# I'm trying to settle dynamic title for any page equal to search input value

Tags: php, title

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="sample" value="" name="sample" />
<title><?php echo $value ?></title>
```

so as I said before I'm trying to settle dynamic title for any page equal to search input value

Comment: This `<title><?php if(isset($_POST['sample'])){ echo $_POST['sample']; }else{ echo 'default title'; } ?></title>` ?

Comment: Do you want to see the search keyword as a title at the action page of form submit?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i need somethink like this

Comment: <title><?php echo $value ?></title>

Comment: EXactly that but instead of $_POST;  $_GET

Comment: <title><?php if(isset($_GET['sample'])){ echo $_GET['sample']; }else{ echo 'default title'; } ?></title>

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a search query is a value set in the query-string of the current URL, such as:

> /search?query=pizza

In PHP, you can access this via the `$_GET` superglobal:

```
<?php echo $_GET['query']; ?>
```

If there isn't a query set, this on its own may lead to a warning/error, so you'll want to verify it's set first:

```
<title>
    Search
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
        echo ' - ' . $_GET['query'];
    }
    ?>
</title>
```

**Warning**: Make sure to always sanitize the output first though, otherwise you could introduce security vulnerabilities such as [Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). To sanitize, try [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities), for example.

```
<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['query']); ?>
```